# Meek bridges in future tails version，super anticiped

Tags: tails, meek

I've been searching for such news for years, and the most recent discussion about adding meek bridges in Tails is in 2018, still no answer. the most important issue in China is we can barely use meek with tor since obs3 or 4 total dead. When can Tails be equipped with tor that could beat the GFW is highly anticipated, I guarantee you every single Chinese who would like to use Tails, such powerful tools to search for freedom and eager to connect to the world, will agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment on the Tor blog for June 24, 2019, that indicates that private obfs4 bridges work in China. https://blog.torproject.org/tors-new-anti-censorship-team-defending-open-internet